# How to Show sort list in edit using laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to show a sort list on the edit page when I click to edit button so just related id is showing into the selection field but I want to show all sort id list into the selection field how can I resolve this issue?

**Controller**

```
                       public function editmenu($id)
                       {

                        $menu=Navigations::find($id);

                        return view('admin.menu.editmenu',compact('menu'));

                       }
```

**edit page view**

```
            <form   method="post"  action="{{route('update.menu',$menu->id)}}"    >
            @csrf
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2"></div>
            <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label for="simpleinput">Navigation </label>
            <input type="text" id="simpleinput" name="menu"  value="{{$menu->Nav_menu}}" 
            placeholder="Enter menu" class="form-control ">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
            <label for="example-select">Sort Position</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="example-select">
            <option>{{$menu->sort_position}}</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div> <!-- end card-body-->
            </div> <!-- end card-->
            <div class="page-title-right">
            <button   type="submit"  id="btnsubmit"   class="btn btn-danger waves-effect 
            waves-light col-lg-3">Update</button>
            </div>
            </div><!-- end col -->
            </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end row --> 
             </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$menu=Navigations::find($id)->orderBy('id', 'ASC'); //'ASC' for ascending order and 'DESC' for descending order
```

OR

```
$menu=Navigations::find($id)->orderBy('sort_position', 'ASC'); //'ASC' for ascending order and 'DESC' for descending order
```

Comment: I have used this code but i facing error https://flareapp.io/share/4m4WyW5M#F48

Comment: Try this

$menu=Navigations::find($id)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->first();